# In Android how to add text as watermark on already recorded video with ffmpeg?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, watermark, drawtext

I am trying to set text as a watermark on already recorded video but it is not working. As I tried image.png as a water mark and it works by following this url http://androidwarzone.blogspot.in/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html

Command for apply image as watermark on already recorded video:

```
String[] complexCommand = {"ffmpeg","-y" ,"-i", videoPathHere,"-strict",
"experimental", "-vf", "movie=" 
+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() 
+ "/watermarkImg.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]",
"-s", "160x120","-r", "30", "-b", "15496k", "-vcodec", "mpeg4","-ab", "48000", 
"-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", 
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/watermark.mp4"};
```

but when I tried to implement text as watermark its not working:

```
String[] complexCommand = {"ffmpeg", "-y" , "-i", videoPathHere, "-strict", "experimental", 
"-vf", "drawtext=fontfile=" + file + ":text=TestText", "-s", "160x120", "-r", "30", 
"-b", "15496k", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", 
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/watermark.mp4"};
```

Even I tried this also 
https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15551/ffmpeg-drawtext-filter-create-transparent-background-with-text

but it is also not working in my case.

So, what is going wrong with adding text as watermark?

I make changes in commenad from ;text=TestText to :text=TestText then it shows given error.

07-23 10:58:07.595: I/Videokit(28832): libvideokit.so loaded
07-23 10:58:07.595: I/Videokit(28832): args is not NULL
07-23 10:58:07.595: I/Videokit(28832): more then one arg
07-23 10:58:07.595: I/Videokit(28832): function symbol found
07-23 10:58:07.595: D/Videokit(28832): Calling videokit run via loader
07-23 10:58:07.595: I/Videokit(28832): vk ffmpeg sdcardPath: /data/user/0/valamovie.com/files/ 
07-23 10:58:07.595: D/Videokit(28832): call licenseCheckComplex
07-23 10:58:07.595: I/Videokit(28832): licenseCheck in path: /data/user/0/valamovie.com/files/ 
07-23 10:58:07.595: I/Videokit(28832): isLicExistsComplex...
07-23 10:58:07.595: I/Videokit(28832): trying to open /data/user/0/valamovie.com/files//ffmpeglicense.lic 
07-23 10:58:07.595: I/Videokit(28832): license file found...
07-23 10:58:07.596: I/Videokit(28832): You used 0 of your 15 trial days. 
07-23 10:58:07.596: D/Videokit(28832): license check rc: 0
07-23 10:58:07.596: D/Videokit(28832): run() called
07-23 10:58:07.670: A/libc(28832): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x10 in tid 28832 (valamovie.com)
07-23 10:58:07.771: A/DEBUG(152): *****               *****
07-23 10:58:07.771: A/DEBUG(152): Build fingerprint: 'Lava/PixelV1/PixelV1_sprout:6.0/MRA58V/eng.admin.20160419.120644:user/release-keys'
07-23 10:58:07.771: A/DEBUG(152): Revision: '0'
07-23 10:58:07.771: A/DEBUG(152): ABI: 'arm'
07-23 10:58:07.771: A/DEBUG(152): pid: 28832, tid: 28832, name: valamovie.com  >>> valamovie.com <<<
07-23 10:58:07.772: A/DEBUG(152): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x10
07-23 10:58:07.789: A/DEBUG(152):     r0 00000000  r1 00000001  r2 0000001e  r3 00000000
07-23 10:58:07.789: A/DEBUG(152):     r4 b8ae87c0  r5 b8ae7fb0  r6 00000000  r7 b8b22500
07-23 10:58:07.789: A/DEBUG(152):     r8 9ee64cc4  r9 b8a1fad0  sl b8b625d0  fp 00000000
07-23 10:58:07.789: A/DEBUG(152):     ip b6d875dc  sp bea3e340  lr 9e3969ac  pc 9e395bb8  cpsr 600f0010
07-23 10:58:07.791: A/DEBUG(152): backtrace:
07-23 10:58:07.791: A/DEBUG(152):     #00 pc 0007cbb8  /data/app/valamovie.com-1/lib/arm/libvideokit.so
07-23 10:58:08.503: W/ActivityManager(557):   Force finishing activity valamovie.com/.Ui.addNewProject
07-23 10:58:08.504: A/DEBUG(152): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_00
07-23 10:58:08.504: E/DEBUG(152): AM write failed: Broken pipe
07-23 10:58:08.505: I/BootReceiver(557): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_00 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
07-23 10:58:08.527: W/InputDispatcher(557): channel '86e38ae valamovie.com/valamovie.com.Ui.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
07-23 10:58:08.528: E/InputDispatcher(557): channel '86e38ae valamovie.com/valamovie.com.Ui.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-23 10:58:08.529: W/InputDispatcher(557): channel 'e50713f valamovie.com/valamovie.com.Ui.addNewProject (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
07-23 10:58:08.529: E/InputDispatcher(557): channel 'e50713f valamovie.com/valamovie.com.Ui.addNewProject (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-23 10:58:08.531: W/ActivityManager(557): Exception thrown during pause

Comment: Did you get solution of this error?

Answer (score 0):

This - `";text=TestText"` should be `":text=TestText"`

Comment: thanks @Mulvya ,I tried now it start crashes i edit my post with list of error shows after apply this changes.

Comment: You're getting a segmentation fault. You need to use a different FFmpeg binary.

Comment: any reference for this, actually FFmpeg is new for me

Comment: See this msg in the output: `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)`. The error isn't produced by FFmpeg but by libvideokit. Don't know what that is, but I suggest using a different FFmpeg binary unless you know how to correct it.